# Powershell SQL query to Excel

Tags: sql, excel, powershell

I am new to Powershell and I need some help with this. I have a query from SQL that needs to create 1 Excel with multiple worksheets based on a Suburb,also last sheet needs to be called all Suburbs and has all the data.
So far I have been creating multiple Queries and once the files are saved I use another script to convert multiple workbooks into one excel and email it. Its becoming very time consuming since the Suburbs are changing weekly.
Thank you

```
> # ADELAIDE    
> 
> $query = "     
> SELECT     
>        Market    
>       ,Customer ID    
>       ,Suburb    
>       ,Product     
> From    A few tables  
> Group By  
>       Market    
>       ,Customer ID    
>       ,Suburb    
>       ,Product     
> "         
> $csvFilePath = "c:\Scripts\CBA\CSV\Adelaide.txt"     
> $excelFilePath = "c:\scripts\CBA\Excel\Adelaide.xls"     
> $instanceName = "TestServer"  
> $QueryDB = 'Test_Database'     
> $Username = 'buggsbunny'     
> $Password = 'looneytunes'     
> $results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $instanceName -Database     $QueryDB -Username $Username -Password $Password
> $results | Export-Csv  -delimiter "`t"  $csvFilePath   -NoTypeInformation| %     {$_.Replace('"','')}
> $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
> $excel.visible = $False
> $excel.displayalerts=$False
> $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($csvFilePath)     
> $workSheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)      
> $resize = $workSheet.UsedRange     
> $resize.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null      
> $xlExcel8 = 51    
> $workbook.SaveAs($excelFilePath,$xlExcel8)     
> $workbook.Close()    
> $excel.quit()      
> $excel = $null
```

Answer (score 0):

Why duplicate the data in different suburb sheets and the "all Suburbs" sheet? Just create one sheet for all suburbs, then use formulas or pivot tables to filter the data for individual suburbs. You would not even need Powershell to do that. Excel can access SQL data and you just need to click one button to refresh.

If you insist on splitting suburbs into individual sheets, consider creating Power Queries for each sheet. When there's new data click Refresh All and you're done.

Comment: This report needs to be emailed daily to different customers. I dont want users to waste time with creating sheets and emailing. Customers want the sheets separated by suburbs and last one with everything. No pivot tables unfortunately. Thank you